# Does importrange not work on Google Sheets embedded XLSX files?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange, microsoft-excel

[The ImportRange documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) mentions nothing about not supporting XLSX embedded files.

But when I try it, it claims it has no permission (whereas I'm an editor in the file I try to import).

Does it mean ImportRange doesn't support such files? If so, is this lack of support documented anywhere?

[image: XLSX in Google Sheets]

[image: Permission issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`importrange()`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340) function can only read data from Google Sheets and therefore cannot read data from Microsoft Excel files, even though you can view and edit such files with Google Sheets. I do not think the official documentation mentions this limitation.

To use `importrange()` with your spreadsheet, you must convert it. To convert a Microsoft Excel, LibreOffice Calc or OpenOffice Calc file to a Google Sheet, open the file in Google Sheets and choose **File > Save as Google Sheets**. You can also use Google Drive to convert the spreadsheet to a Google Sheet, or open a new Google Sheet and choose **File > Import** to bring the data in. Then refer to the new file instead of the original in your `importrange()` formulas.

Alternatively, use **File > Share > Publish to web > CSV** and use `importdata()` instead of `importrange()` to bring the data to the target spreadsheet.

Comment: I don't see an option in LibreOffice Calc v 7.3.7.2 to save a spreadsheet as Google Sheets  but saving to Google Drive and Import works for information.

Comment: Open the LibreOffice Calc file _in Google Sheets_, then choose **File > Save as Google Sheets**.